# Change number of bands in rasterio

Tags: python-3.x, rasterio, satellite-image, sentinel2

I'm working with some TIFF images, and I want to add another band to an existing image.

Here's the code that I use to read the image:

```
# Read the image
image = rasterio.open('input.tiff')

with rasterio.open("input.tiff", 'r+') as src:
   crs = rasterio.crs.CRS({"init": "epsg:4326"})
   src.crs = crs
```

With this code, I'm able to change the CRS: here's the meta of image:

```
{'driver': 'GTiff',
 'dtype': 'uint8',
 'nodata': None,
 'width': 524,
 'height': 499,
 'count': 3,
 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326),
 'transform': Affine(1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0)}
```

I want to change the *count* value from 3 to 4.

I'm using *rasterio*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the metadata using `.profile` and then update it.

```
with rasterio.open('input.tiff') as r:
      profile = r.profile

profile.update(count = 4)
profile.update(crs = 'EPSG:32643')
```